# Export shared mailbox permissions to .csv

Tags: powershell, office365, export-to-csv

I need to learn how to make a script that gets all users that have access to a shared mailbox in our business.

For example:

shared mailbox: shared_admin@business.com

I would like to export as a .csv like this:

```
| Username | Access | Mailbox |
| john.peterson | Full Access | shared_admin@business.com |
| anne.wall | Full Access | shared_admin@business.com |
| jason.doe | Full Access | shared_admin@business.com |
| tim.carlson |Full Access | shared_admin@business.com |
```

Comment: Which code did you try at this point and what were your challenges?

Comment: Have a look at [Get-MailboxPermission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-mailboxpermission?view=exchange-ps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First install the [Exchange Online PowerShell module v2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps#install-and-maintain-the-exo-v2-module):

```
Install-Module -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement
```

Then the following code should do the job:

```
# Connect to Exchange Online
Connect-ExchangeOnline

# Retrieve mailbox permissions
$sharedMailbox = 'shared_admin@business.com'
$permissions = Get-MailboxPermission -Identity $sharedMailbox

# Format the permissions to have the column names you asked for
$formattedPermissions = $permissions `
| Select-Object -Property @{Name='Username';Expression={$_.User}},@{Name='Access';Expression={$_.AccessRights}},@{Name='Mailbox';Expression={$sharedMailbox}}

# Export to CSV, delimiter can be adjusted
$formattedPermissions | Export-Csv -Path permissions.csv -Delimiter ',' -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you Chris. This worked out perfectly.